# How to display the most recently inserted ID in a create view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am using MVC to make an application and I have an entity called `Week`. In the create page, I want to display the ID of the most recent week created just to help the user avoid putting in the wrong week number. For example, when I am creating Week number 3, I want it to display "The last week made was Week 2" above the input box or something along those lines. I have tried with the following code but it doesn't seem to work and I do not know why.

`Create` in the `WeekController`:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="WeekID,YearID")] Week week)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Weeks.Add(week);
                db.SaveChanges();

                int latestKey = week.WeekID;
                ViewBag.latestKey = latestKey;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Year");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Maybe this week already exists. If not, try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }

        ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(db.Years, "YearID", "YearID", week.YearID);
        return View(week);
    }
```

And the `Create` page in the week view:

```
@model Utility3.Models.Week

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h1>Add Week</h1>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @*<h4>Week</h4>*@
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        <p>Last week made was: @ViewBag.latestKey</p>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Week number", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WeekID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WeekID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Year", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("YearID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearID)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Year List", "Index", "Year")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I tried saving the ID of the week created last and pass it in with `ViewBag` but it doesn't work.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: What language is this? ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I did not mention that.

Comment: you are setting the week Id in the post, and it should be in the get create actionresult, if you want i can make a sample code for you to show you how

Comment: Thank you, I actually just figured that out and it is posting "0" in the view now for the ID, but when I create a week and go into it again, it stays at zero so it's not actually displaying the latest ID. I would very much appreciate some sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy, you are already passing the Week Model back to your view , so instead of using Viewbag, just use Model.WeekID like this :

```
<p>Last week made was: @Model.WeekID</p>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I feel stupid for not thinking of that! But when I try it and go to the create page I get this error: " `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` ". How can I get passed this so I can get to the create page and then make a week so that then there'll be something to display.

Comment: The problem is that after your saving the Week in the dbcontext, you are setting the Viewbag for the Index page not the Create Page in these line      : ViewBag.latestKey = latestKey;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Year");

Instead you should either set the ViewBag and return to the Create View, or replace the above two line with  :    return View(Week);
otherwise of course you'll get Object refrence null. coz nothing is passed to the create view!

Comment: Okay. I tried displaying the value in the index page too just to see if that's where it was, but that didn't work either?

Comment: I think to avoid confusion back and forth, the easiest solution here is to use Session["Week"]=week;
in this case all views can have access to it, whether you want to first redirect to index and go back to create! and then kill it when your done with it like that : session["week"]=null;

Comment: I've never used Session. I will look it up now, thanks.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of using Session here?

Comment: in your controller :

 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Weeks.Add(week);
                db.SaveChanges();

                int latestKey = week.WeekID;
                ViewBag.latestKey = latestKey;
                  Session["week"]=week;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Year");
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
in your View your going to say : 

 <p>Last week made was: @(Session["week"] as week).weekID 
I use session all the time because it retains value.

Comment: Sorry I am so long geting back to you. In `@(Session["week"] as week).weekID`, "as week" is giving me the error: "The type or namespace 'week' could not be found". Am I missing something?

Comment: it looks like you didn't reference the week in your View as a model :
@model Utility3.Models.Week

Comment: do it like this @(Session["week"] as Utility3.Models.Week).weekID

Comment: When I run it first, it prints out: `Last week made was: .WeekID`. Then when I create a week and go back to the page it prints: `Last week made was: Utility3.Models.Week.WeekID`?